# High Battery Drain with CM11 Stable on HTC One due to MediaServer

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery

What's the best way to fix a high battery drain?

I had been using an old nightly build on my HTC One (since no stable had yet been released for it), and I had no battery issues. Just sitting in my pocket all day, the battery would still be at 75% by day's end.

Then I upgraded a week ago to the most recent stable (CM 11-20141112-SNAPSHOT-M12-m7), and now my battery's completely dead in about 3 hours even if I don't use my phone.

The battery statistics app says that the "Mediaserver" is consuming 45% and "Google Services" is consuming another 39%, which seems insane. Historically, "screen" is usually the biggest consumer, but that's now at only 8%.

Googling shows this is a common problem with CM, and there's a ton of different causes and fixes. What's the best solution? I picked a stable release because I thought...well, it would be stable and relatively bug free. It seems counter-intuitive to upgrade to a nightly to fix one bug, while likely introducing more.

A common solution mentioned is to "disable Google Now", but I don't have any such app installed.

Another solution is to disable location reporting for Google Services, but they don't mention how. I think they mean [disabling location reporting](http://trendblog.net/disable-location-services-android/) under "Google Settings", but this effectively disables all apps that use GPS, and I use Google Maps and Navigation quite frequently.

Comment: Did you find in your research terms like keep awake, wakelock (partial, kernel, etc) and apps like [Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) , [Amplify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryansteckler.nlpunbounce), [Battery Stats Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.bstats), [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify), [DS Battery Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.batrsaver), etc. What are your results with them?

Comment: I don't remember a one-stop solution in an answer on AE, but there are many good answers. You can try this simple search on AE http://android.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=battery%20drain